# stretching my image view

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a viewpager into which I'm inflating an imageview;
I used the android:scaleType="fitXY"
but there's still some black around the image why and how can I stretch it so that it be as if it was a background?
thanks.

layout of the viewpager:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Introduction_Activity"

  >

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/imgs_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

image view layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_intro"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you using android:src for setting background?

Comment: I am using img_v.setImageResource(position); because it's in the viewpager

Comment: android:src is to set imageview source, android:background will set the background of the view, you can try to set your drawable to android:background instead of src, btw, does your imageview have layout_width and layout_height = match_parent?

Comment: yes my layout width and height are match parent and I tried to set the background of the imageview instead of the ressource got the same result will add some of my code;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to remove padding from relative layout, they are eating space from the ViewPager

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: yes I noticed that I am really sorry for asking this question it seems that I didn't pay attention to that, sorry and thanks.

Comment: @User np, just please keep the xml layout in your question so it's completed

Answer (score 1):

This is not clear here may be you use a padding on your view pager or a view flipper due to that the margin left and right occurs if you do this thing you cant stretch it to the maximum width..
so try to remove padding and works with the weight to set the viewpager size

Comment: I am sorry I didn't see that I have padding on my realtive layout, it seems that because I am a little bit late I didn't see that, thanks I upvoted your answer.